# Получить _csrf-backend и авторизоваться

Tags: php, curl

Хочу авторизоваться cURL'ом на странице и получить с нее данные.
Заметил что при авторизации, точнее при переходе на сайт, генерируется каждый раз новое значение **_csrf-backend** , и когда ввести логин/пароль и нажать *Войти* - POST'ом передается этот самый сгенерированный **_csrf-backend**.

В форме он так выглядит:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf-backend" value="m_C6kJjl6jmbREgSHpCAwIs8JkfekqhTtN7Lt1a-ftOqwdj2_4O6Ya4AL3dSovWC_nJ8IJfDmxHlkqXYD_Mc5Q==">
```

Еще я заметил что он есть в шапке сайта

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf-backend"><meta name="csrf-token" content="m_C6kJjl6jmbREgSHpCAwIs8JkfekqhTtN7Lt1a-ftOqwdj2_4O6Ya4AL3dSovWC_nJ8IJfDmxHlkqXYD_Mc5Q==">
```

Как мне его получить до того как cURL будет авторизовываться на сайте (ну и подставить для авторизации).

Вот моя функция:

```
function login($url, $login, $pass){
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"LoginForm[email]=".$login."&LoginForm[password]=".$pass."&_csrf-backend=".$csrf."&login-button=");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
   $result=curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Это yii2 ? или другой фреймворк ?

Comment: @madfan41k точно сказать не могу. сайт не мой...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так вывести. Если вернет то это yii2

```
function login($url, $login, $pass){
   $csrf = Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken();
   echo $csrf; die;
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"LoginForm[email]=".$login."&LoginForm[password]=".$pass."&_csrf-backend=".$csrf."&login-button=");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
   $result=curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: нет, я же пишу просто скрипт на php, без фреймворков. я думал вы спрашиваете на чем работает сайт который парситься....

Comment: тогда я не понимаю вопрос, в чем проблема в том месте где вы с формы получаете логин и пароль, получить еще и csrf и передать его в ваш метод login ?